# How to selectively exec some sql statement in a sql script, not in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm writing a SQL script, which should contain some selection logic such as:

```
  if: we have some foreign key that referenced this table
  then: delete all of those.
  drop: this table
```

This series of SQL statements is not included in a stored procedure so I cannot use the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
use test;
create table test01 ( a integer, b char, c datetime );
create table test02 ( a char, b datetime, c integer );
```

"MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys..." [MySQL Doc on foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```
create index test02_idx1 on test02(c);
create index test01_idx1 on test01(a);
alter table test02 add foreign key ( c ) references test01(a);

use information_schema;
select 
  c.constraint_schema
 ,c.constraint_name 
 ,c.table_name
 ,c.referenced_table_name
 ,CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',c.table_name,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',c.constraint_name,'; DROP TABLE ',c.referenced_table_name,';') as command
from
  key_column_usage c
  ,table_constraints t 
where 
  c.constraint_name = t.constraint_name 
  and c.referenced_table_name = 'test01';

+-------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| constraint_schema | constraint_name | table_name | referenced_table_name | command                                                               |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test              | test02_ibfk_1   | test02     | test01                | ALTER TABLE test02 DROP FOREIGN KEY test02_ibfk_1; DROP TABLE test01; |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

Becuase You have series of statements not included in stored procedure, You need to secure three things:

- print the commands ( `select 'drop foreign key; drop table;';` )
- disable borders and columns' headers ( `-B --disable-column-names` )
- print output to a file ( `> output.sql` or `tee` )

`mysql -B -u user -p --disable-column-names < script.sql`

You need to write output to a file. There are two methods:

**1. One execution**

`mysql -B -u user -p --disable-column-names < script.sql > output.sql`

```
select 
 CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',c.table_name,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',c.constraint_name,'; DROP TABLE ',c.referenced_table_name,';') as command
from
  key_column_usage c
  ,table_constraints t 
where 
  c.constraint_name = t.constraint_name 
  and c.referenced_table_name = 'test01';
source output.sql
quit;
```

**2. Two executions**

...or inside `script.sql`:

```
tee output.sql
select 
 CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',c.table_name,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',c.constraint_name,'; DROP TABLE ',c.referenced_table_name,';') as command
from
  key_column_usage c
  ,table_constraints t 
where 
  c.constraint_name = t.constraint_name 
  and c.referenced_table_name = 'test01';
notee
quit;
```

then

```
mysql -u user -p < output.sql
```